# Multiplex grid of LEDs with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, wiring, led-matrix

I'm trying to multiplex a grid of LEDs directly from a microcontroller but all the schematics I'm seeing online show how to multiplex to some kind of IC chip or board that isn't the main processor. I want to know if there's anything different about coding / wiring a grid of LEDs directly to a microcontroller (specifically the ATmega2560). Besides deciding which pin to wire rows and columns to, does wiring directly to the microcontroller mean I need to add some extra components? (I have enough pins, don't get me wrong)

Thanks!

Comment: The snarky answer is probably. What is your thinking? Why do you think there might be a need for more circuitry? Let's see if we can get you  working it out.

Comment: I'm trying to multiplex a 10x20 grid of 3mm LEDs from the atmega2560, @DiBosco
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: > ... does wiring directly to the microcontroller mean I need to add some extra components? Although 2560 can do it, I would use some dedicated controller, I2C (or other...) programmable ...

Comment: Search for example "MAX7219 LED Display Dot led Matrix MCU Control Module"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are lucky since the AVR and the PICs (most of them) have high current outputs capable of driving directly a led. So for *one* led you just need a suitable drop resistor (usually a 330 or 470 ohm for 5V supplys).

When you are *matrix* multiplexing however the common line needs to be buffered since it needs to handle the current of a potentially whole lit row/column of leds. In this case usually you drive the anode from the GPIO (using a resistor) and complete the ground connection for the row/column with a transistor (BJT or MOSFET, your choice).

From a coding point of view you drive *one* common row/column at a time and *all* the relevant columns/rows for that common. Do it fast enough and you have successfully multiplexed your display.

Be careful to not *ever* turn one more than one common to avoid damaging your GPIOs.

EDIT: there is a special case which only uses the MCU without any buffer hardware. It has limitations however, search for "Charlieplexing" (IIRC it was first published by Microchip for the PICs)

Comment: Even if the common row/driver is separate, but LEDs still driven from IO pins, the limitations for supply pins and IO pin groups are still present. If limit is 100mA per group then that might be 10mA per LED in a matrix. The supply pin will not allow more than 200mA, and that's already the absolute maximum rating.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the total 'ground/supply' current for the gpio cells. Probably because after say 8 LED it becomes simpler to simply buy a led driver

Comment: True. A typical LED driver chip would have larger nominal currents than the absolute maximum ratings of the MCU. So the MCU does not really have that high current sink/source ability.

Comment: Commonly MCUs have only 2-4mA of available GPIO current (especially on the 3.3V parts), the AVR and PIC are notable exception. So from ancient times you alway buffered them in some way (transistors, logic buffers dedicated drivers). The PIC users are simply lucky to have extra-strength GPIOs. Also LED driver parts usually have some provision for constant current drive (which is the recommended way to drive a LED).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with wiring LEDs directly to a MCU means that there is not much current available from the IO pins as they are not designed to drive loads directly.

That is why external chips such as LED driver chips are used, as they can drive the LEDs with enough current, and they also do the multiplexing for you, and provide a handy low pin count bus for you to access the LED matrix.

So you can do the multiplexing yourself but it will still require a chip or discrete transistors to drive the matrix with enough current.

For the ATMega2560, there are per-pin and per-group and per-supply pin limits for current. You can see the limts from the datasheet, but basically, it is not possible to have much more than 20mA per IO pin at 5V supply, or much more than 10mA per pin at 3V. So driving a 10x10 matrix directly from IO pins means each LED must be limited to 1-2 mA.

Comment: 1-2 mA? I was planning 10x20, would this cause a problem? One of my concerns of using multiplexer chips is that they don't usually come with 10 pins I can use, it's usually around 8. Would the atmega2560 have trouble with a 10x20 matrix of 3mm blue LEDs? (the blue ones are usually easier to power)

Comment: It depends how you would connect them and what kind of multiplexer you mean. It still does not change the fact that available current to power LEDs with current sourced or sinked directly by MCU is limited. Sure if you power one LED at a time then you have 10-20mA available for that one LED, but of you power 10 LEDs simultaneously then the IO pin is still limited to 10-20mA if no driving circuitry is used. Blue ones are actually harder to power since they have higher voltage rating.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem driving a multiplexed LED array with ATmega2560, as long as you don't exceed the 20 mA per pin limitation. You can experiment what current level you need. You might be able to get away with 2 mA per LED, which would allow you to drive 10 LED in a row all at once.

External chips have the benefit of not blocking/being blocked by your main program to drive LEDs. Second most useful function IMO is brighness control by PWM or linear.

Comment: Most MCUs also have a port-wide maximum, as well. Usually, this isn't enough that all of the port pins can drive their maximum current. Another thing to be aware of and find in the absolute maximums, when provided.

Comment: Yes, and Atmega has a chip wide maximum, but no port-specific from what I can recall. We might have built the circuit differently in our heads, as it's not clearly defined, but in my circuit it won't be the limiting factor.